# asp.net mvc paging duplicating page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, pagination, asp.net-ajax

I'm having a problem with paging. I've had this working in the past but now it doesn't. It's specifically relating to the pagemore button, and not the general paging (which works fine). The javascript pager used to load extra replies with ajax but now all it does is duplicate the whole page.

I've had the same thing in the past and it's always been related to the route but I can't see what's wrong here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Main view:

```
<div class="pagerSummary">
        @T("Displaying <span class=\"firstItem\">{0}</span> to <span class=\"lastItem\">{1}</span> of <span class=\"totalItems\">{2}</span> messages",
            PageIndex * Config.UI.MessagesPerPage + 1,
            PageIndex * Config.UI.MessagesPerPage + Model.Messages.Count,
            Model.Replies)
    </div>
}
<div id="pagerClient" style="display:none;"><a href="#" onclick="pager.more();return false;">@Html.Img("~/images/loadingMini.gif", "") @T("Show more messages")</a></div>
@Html.Pager(Config.UI.MessagesPerPage, PageIndex, Model.Replies, S("Previous"), S("Next"))

@Html.Script("~/scripts/pager.js")

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    quoting.init();
    pager.init('@Url.Action("PageMore", "Topics", new{id=Model.Id, name=Model.Title})', '@Url.Action("PageUntil", "Topics", new{id=Model.Id, name=Model.Title})', '@T("The browser has lost session, click ok to return to the login page")');
});
</script
```

The Routes:

```
 <add url="topic/{id}/{name}/page-more" controller="Topics" action="PageMore">
        <constraints>
    <add key="forum" value="all" />
    <add key="name" value="[\w\-%]+?" />
            <add key="id" value="^\d+$" />
        </constraints>
    <defaults>
    <add key="forum" value="all" />
    <add key="page" value="0" />

        </defaults>

    </add>
<add url="topic/{id}/{name}/page-until" controller="Topics" action="PageUntil">
        <constraints>
    <add key="forum" value="all" />
    <add key="name" value="[\w\-%]+?" />
            <add key="id" value="^\d+$" />
        </constraints>
    <defaults>
    <add key="forum" value="all" />
    <add key="page" value="0" />
        </defaults>

    </add>
  <add url="topic/{id}/{name}/{page}" controller="Topics" action="Detail">
        <constraints>
    <add key="name" value="[\w\-%]+?" />
            <add key="id" value="^\d+$" />
            <add key="page" value="^\d+$" />
        </constraints>
        <defaults>
    <add key="forum" value="all" />
    <add key="page" value="0" />
        </defaults>
    </add>
```

The Pager Js File

```
(function(d)   {d.each(["backgroundColor","borderBottomColor","borderLeftColor","borderRightColor","borderTopColor","color","outlineColor"],function(f,e){d.fx.step[e]=function(g){if(!g.colorInit)  {g.start=c(g.elem,e);g.end=b(g.end);g.colorInit=true}g.elem.style[e]="rgb("+  [Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((g.pos*(g.end[0]-  g.start[0]))+g.start[0]),255),0),Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((g.pos*(g.end[1]-  g.start[1]))+g.start[1]),255),0),Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((g.pos*(g.end[2]-  g.start[2]))+g.start[2]),255),0)].join(",")+")"}});function b(f){var   e;if(f&&f.constructor==Array&&f.length==3){return f}if(e=/rgb\(\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]  {1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*\)/.exec(f))  {return[parseInt(e[1]),parseInt(e[2]),parseInt(e[3])]}if(e=/rgb\(\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-  9]+)?)\%\s*,\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*,\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*\)/.exec(f))  {return[parseFloat(e[1])*2.55,parseFloat(e[2])*2.55,parseFloat(e[3])*2.55]}if(e=/#([a-fA-  F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/.exec(f))  {return[parseInt(e[1],16),parseInt(e[2],16),parseInt(e[3],16)]}if(e=/#([a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-  F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9])/.exec(f)){return[parseInt(e[1]+e[1],16),parseInt(e[2]+e[2],16),parseInt(e[3]+e[3],16)]}if(e=/rgba\(0, 0, 0, 0\)/.exec(f)){return a.transparent}return a[d.trim(f).toLowerCase()]}function c(g,e){var f;do{f=d.curCSS(g,e);if(f!=""&&f!="transparent"||d.nodeName(g,"body")){break}e="backgroundColor"}while(g=g.parentNode);return b(f)}var a={aqua:[0,255,255],azure:[240,255,255],beige:[245,245,220],black:[0,0,0],blue:[0,0,255],brown:[165,42,42],cyan:[0,255,255],darkblue:[0,0,139],darkcyan:[0,139,139],darkgrey:[169,169,169],darkgreen:[0,100,0],darkkhaki:[189,183,107],darkmagenta:[139,0,139],darkolivegreen:[85,107,47],darkorange:[255,140,0],darkorchid:[153,50,204],darkred:[139,0,0],darksalmon:[233,150,122],darkviolet:[148,0,211],fuchsia:[255,0,255],gold:[255,215,0],green:[0,128,0],indigo:[75,0,130],khaki:[240,230,140],lightblue:[173,216,230],lightcyan:[224,255,255],lightgreen:[144,238,144],lightgrey:[211,211,211],lightpink:[255,182,193],lightyellow:[255,255,224],lime:[0,255,0],magenta:[255,0,255],maroon:[128,0,0],navy:[0,0,128],olive:[128,128,0],orange:[255,165,0],pink:[255,192,203],purple:[128,0,128],violet:[128,0,128],red:[255,0,0],silver:[192,192,192],white: [255,255,255],yellow:[255,255,0],transparent:[255,255,255]}})(jQuery);
var pager = 
{
firstItem : -1
, totalItems : -1
, lastItem : -1
, tempText : null
, enabled : false
, postUrl : null
, postUrlToId : null
, forbiddenMessage : ""
,
init : function(postUrl, postUrlToId, forbiddenMessage)
{
    if ($(".firstItem").length > 0)
    {
        pager.firstItem = parseInt($(".firstItem").text(), 10);
        pager.lastItem = parseInt($(".lastItem").text(), 10);
        pager.totalItems = parseInt($(".totalItems").text(), 10);
        pager.enabled = true;
        pager.forbiddenMessage = forbiddenMessage;

        pager.postUrl = postUrl;
        pager.postUrlToId = postUrlToId;
        if (pager.firstItem == 1)
        {
            $("div.pager").hide();
            pager.showCurrentStatus();
            if (window.location.hash)
            {
                pager.navigateToId();
            }
        }
    }
    $(document).trigger("dataLoaded");
}
,
loadingStart : function()
{
    //loading
    pager.enabled = false;
    $("#pagerClient").toggleClass("loading");
}
,
loadingEnd : function()
{
    $("#pagerClient").toggleClass("loading");
    pager.enabled = true;
}
,
showCurrentStatus : function()
{
    $(".lastItem").text(pager.lastItem.toString());
    if (pager.lastItem == pager.totalItems)
    {
        //TODO: Don't hide it, just disable it
        $("#pagerClient").stop().hide();
        $("div.toolbar li.showAll").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#pagerClient").slideDown();
        $("div.toolbar li.showAll").show();
    }
}
,
more : function()
{
    if (pager.enabled && pager.lastItem < pager.totalItems)
    {
        var fromId = $("#messages > li:last").attr("id").substring(3);
        pager.post(pager.postUrl, {from:fromId}, pager.moreCallback);
        pager.loadingStart();
    }
}
,
moreCallback : function(htmlText)
{
    $("#messages").append(htmlText);
    pager.lastItem = $("#messages > li").length;
    pager.loadingEnd();
    pager.showCurrentStatus();
    $(document).trigger("dataLoaded");
}
,
navigateToId : function()
{
    if (pager.enabled && $(window.location.hash).length == 0)
    {
        //Load messages until that id
        if (window.location.hash.indexOf("msg") == 1)
        {
            pager.loadingStart();
            var lastMsg = window.location.hash.substring(4);
            var firstMsg = $("#messages > li:last").attr("id").substring(3);
            pager.post(pager.postUrlToId,   {firstMsg:firstMsg,lastMsg:lastMsg}, pager.navigateToIdCallback);
        }
    }
    else if ($(window.location.hash).length == 1)
    {
        pager.highlightMessage(window.location.hash);
    }
}
,
navigateToIdCallback : function(htmlText)
{
    $("#messages").append(htmlText);
    pager.lastItem = $("#messages > li").length;
    $("#messages > li:last").addClass("highlight");
    var temp = window.location.hash;
    window.location.hash = "#";
    window.location.hash = temp;
    pager.loadingEnd();
    pager.showCurrentStatus();
    $(document).trigger("dataLoaded");
    pager.highlightMessage(window.location.hash);
}
,
highlightMessage : function(selector)
{
    var original = $(selector).css("backgroundColor");
    $(selector).animate({ 
    backgroundColor: "#DCECF4"
    }, 2000, "linear", function(){
        $(selector).animate({backgroundColor: original}, 2000, "linear", function(){$(selector).css("backgroundColor", null)});
    });
}
,
showAll : function()
{
    if (pager.enabled)
    {
        pager.loadingStart();
        var lastMsg = 1000;
        var firstMsg = $("#messages > li:last").attr("id").substring(3);
        pager.post(pager.postUrlToId, {firstMsg:firstMsg,lastMsg:lastMsg},  pager.showAllCallback);
    }
    return false;
}
,
showAllCallback : function(htmlText)
{
    $("#messages").append(htmlText);
    pager.lastItem = $("#messages > li").length;
    pager.loadingEnd();
    pager.showCurrentStatus();
    $(document).trigger("dataLoaded");
}
,
post : function (url, data, callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: callback,
        dataType: "html",
        statusCode: {
        403: function() {
                if (pager.forbiddenMessage)
                {
                    alert(pager.forbiddenMessage);
                }
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Wasted about 10 hours on this today, am now fedup. Thanks all!

Controllers:

```
    public ActionResult PageMore(int id, string name, string forum, int from)
    {
        var topic = _service.GetWithMessages(id, from, Config.UI.MessagesPerPage);
        if (topic == null)
        {
            return ResultHelper.NotFoundResult(this);
        }


        return View(false, topic);
    }

    public ActionResult PageUntil(int id, string name, string forum, int firstMsg, int lastMsg)
    {
        var topic = _service.GetWithMessages(id, firstMsg, lastMsg-firstMsg);
        if (topic == null)
        {
            return ResultHelper.NotFoundResult(this);
        }

        return View(false, "PageMore", topic);
    }
```

Comment: What does the browser's network tab in the debug console show when you request the `/page-more` url?

Comment: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'from'. On Network it just sais get error, internal server error. text/html. This all used to work, removed it ages ago but decided i wanted it again. so much has changed since :( lol

Comment: What are the parameters for that post? Does it match what your controller expects?

Comment: hey have added the controller code into main post, thanks.

Comment: Right, so does your post to `PageMore` properly send those parameters?

Comment: i just put in the route a default value for from, it then allowed the page to show. when i click show more messages it still adds a duplicate of full page after main div content. Also made the partialview for pagemore.cshtml just text saying hi, still nothing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38132/discussion-between-jasen-and-user1311546)

Comment: I think this is the issue:  

I had this same issue with an MVC4 project.  Your default routing value for page is overriding the parameter you are passing.  Remove the default parameters and pass the values explicitly.

Comment: just thought would give an update, ray you were right. it was the page parameter, as soon as I deleted that it worked fine. Frustrating waste of time when I could have deleted one line, always the way :)